# How do I pass a variable into a payload

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

So I have an endpoint that I am trying to integrate in Python which accepts a POST request and according to the API documentation, the payload is to be formatted this way:

```
payload = "{\r\n\"serviceCode\" : \"V-TV\",\r\n\"type\" : \"DSTV\",\r\n\"smartCardNo\" : \"10441003943\"\r\n}\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n"
```

I want the values of type and smartCardNo to be dynamic, i.e I am going to get the values from a form in the frontend and pass it to the backend but I am finding it difficult to do so.
If I format the payload this way(which of course allows ease of passing variable):

```
{
        "serviceCode": "V-TV",
        "type": "DSTV",
        "smartCardNo" : "10441003943"
  }
```

I get this error:

```
{'required_fields': ['The service code field is required.'], 'message': 'Service Code is not supplied', 'status': '301'}
```

Could anyone tell me how I can pass the values for type and smartCardNo dynamically in the fist format(the format specified in the documentation)....any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If the answer worked for you, please accept it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can simply use the .format()

```
dict_values = {
        "serviceCode": "V-TV",
        "type": "DSTV",
        "smartCardNo" : "10441003943"
  }
    
payload = """{{"serviceCode":"{serviceCode}","type":"{mytype}","smartCardNo":"{smartCardNo}"}}""".format(
        serviceCode = dict_values["serviceCode"],
        mytype = dict_values["type"],
        smartCardNo = dict_values["smartCardNo"]
    )
```

output:

```
'{"serviceCode":"V-TV","type":"DSTV","smartCardNo":"10441003943"}'
```

If you really need the same format as in your `payload` example, simple use:

```
payload = "{{\r\n\"serviceCode\" : \"{serviceCode}\",\r\n\"type\" : \"{mytype}\",\r\n\"smartCardNo\" : \"{smartCardNo}\"\r\n}}\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n".format(
    serviceCode = dict_values["serviceCode"],
    mytype = dict_values["type"],
    smartCardNo = dict_values["smartCardNo"]
)
```

and your output will be:

```
'{\r\n"serviceCode" : "V-TV",\r\n"type" : "DSTV",\r\n"smartCardNo" : "10441003943"\r\n}\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n'
```